Add single bookmark button to top level macOS Safari toolbar
I would like to add a bookmarklet to my Safari window on macOS.
I want the bookmarklet to be available as a button in the top-level Safari toolbar, in the same toolbar as the Back/Forward buttons, address bar, Safari extension buttons, etc.

View > Customize Toolbar... does not seem to show any bookmark-related toolbar buttons for this toolbar
I'm aware that I can View > Show Favorites Bar to display a full "Favorites" bookmark toolbar underneath the address bar. I can display and click a bookmarklet from this toolbar, and uncheck Show Title to display only the favicon.

But I don't want to always see all of my other bookmarks in this bar, or waste the vertical space.
I just want a single button next to the Address bar that opens a single bookmark / invokes a bookmarklet. How can I do this in Safari for macOS? If it cannot be done stock, are there any Safari Extensions that enable the functionality?

You could try creating a Safari extension and adding it to Safari. It will appear near the other extensions.
